# How to create models in loopback in reverse mode

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

Is there any possibility to auto create `loopback.js` database tables model based on already created database. I was aware of creating `loopback models slc`, but I want to create models for tables which are already in database.

Answer (score 0):

Below links will give the solution.

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Discovering+models+from+relational+databases

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Database+discovery+API

Comment: I came to know discovering will not full fill the requirements that we need and that loopback model generator giving to us.